# Color ramp with the same colour scale across different plots in R

Tags: r, colors, maps, raster, color-scheme

I need to create a few raster figures, but keeping color ramp scale the same, but I also want the color ramp to be a smooth gradient. Is it possible to keep a big number of colors(~100 to have a smooth color ramp), but at the same time have a reasonable number of breaks, so that it's readable?

```
library(raster)
library(colorRamps)

r1<- raster(ncol=56, nrow=26)
r1[] <- runif(n=56*26,min=-20,max=15)

r2<- raster(ncol=56, nrow=26)
r2[] <- runif(n=56*26,min=-14,max=68)


brk=seq(-50,70,length.out=100)
col=matlab.like(100)

plot(r1, breaks=brk, col=col)
plot(r2, breaks=brk, col=col)
```

In this case I have a color ramp I wish, but you can't read the breaks labels
[image]

And when I decrease the number of breaks, the color ramp becomes all in one color

```
brk=seq(-50,70,length.out=6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find this easier with `ggplot2`. In the code below the key is, for each plot, to set the same color values for `low`, `mid`, and `high` and the same `limits` in `scale_fill_gradient2`. That guarantees the same data values are mapped to the same colors in each plot. For example:

```
library(rasterVis)
library(ggplot2)

# Reproducible rasters
set.seed(4598)
r1<- raster(ncol=56, nrow=26)
r1[] <- runif(n=56*26,min=-20,max=15)

r2<- raster(ncol=56, nrow=26)
r2[] <- runif(n=56*26,min=-14,max=68)

# Get range of data values across the two rasters
rng = range(c(getValues(r1), getValues(r2)))

gplot(r1) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=value)) +
  ggtitle("r1") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="red", mid="green", high="blue", 
                       midpoint=mean(rng),    # Value that gets the middle color (default is zero)
                       breaks=seq(-100,100,10),  # Set whatever breaks you want
                       limits=c(floor(rng[1]), ceiling(rng[2])))  # Set the same limits for each plot

gplot(r2) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=value)) +
  ggtitle("r2") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="red", mid="green", high="blue", 
                       midpoint=mean(rng),    # Value that gets the middle color (default is zero)
                       breaks=seq(-100,100,10),  # Set whatever breaks you want
                       limits=c(floor(rng[1]), ceiling(rng[2])))  # Set the same limits for each plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can use `at` to define your range (min, max, interval). The smaller interval will produce the smoother color range. see the related question here -- [How to setup step color region in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840734/how-to-setup-step-color-region-in-r) or this post [Locking color key in levelplot in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389920/locking-color-key-in-levelplot-in-r?rq=1)