# How to set up step color regions?

Tags: r, raster, levelplot

With `levelplot`/`spplot` we can use `at` to define the color region range (min, max, interval). My question is: how can I use red for values greater than 29.5?

This is my sample NCDF file --> [download here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6FFDD661570C7D0A!1107&authkey=!ADN3WPrRGws_fV0&ithint=file%2Cnc)

```
 library (raster)
 r <- brick('bali.nc', varname='TEMPERATURE', level=1)

 library(rasterVis)
 jet <- colorRampPalette(
   c('#00007F', 'blue', '#007FFF', 'cyan', 'yellow', '#FF7F00', 'red', '#7F0000')
 )

 # First Figure - without at
 levelplot(r, layer=1, margin=F, contour=F, col.regions=jet)

 # Second Figure - with at
 levelplot(r, layer=1, margin=F, contour=F, col.regions=jet, at=seq(27.5, 29.5, 0.1))
```

[image: Figure A]
[image: Figure B]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the maximum value in the vector of break values, and define the palette accordingly:

```
rMax <- cellStats(r, max)
myAt <- c(seq(27.5, 29.5, 0.1), rMax[1])
myPal <- jet(length(myAt) - 1)

levelplot(r, layer = 1, margin = FALSE,
          at = myAt,
          par.settings = rasterTheme(myPal))
```

[image: levelplot]